Loki-Stack helm in terraform not applying storage class to prometheus and alert manager
I have installed manually loki-stack with promtail in my DEV EKS cluster
helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack \
  --namespace infra \
  --create-namespace \
  --set grafana.enabled=true \
  --set prometheus.enabled=true \
  --set loki.persistence.enabled=true \
  --set loki.persistence.storageClassName=gp2 \
  --set loki.persistence.size=10Gi

and
helm upgrade --install promtail grafana/promtail \
  --namespace infra \
  --set config.lokiAddress=http://loki.infra:3100/loki/api/v1/push \
  --set config.filepath=/var/log/containers/*.log

I tried to replicate the same with Terraform to deploy to my UAT EKS cluster
locals {
  facts = var.tags
}



#########################################
### Deploy Loki 
resource "helm_release" "loki" {
  name       = "loki"
  repository = "https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts"
  chart      = "loki-stack"
  namespace  = "infra"

  values = [
    jsonencode({
      grafana = {
        enabled = true
        additionalDataSources = [{
          name     = "Loki"
          type     = "loki"
          url      = "http://loki.infra.svc.cluster.local:3100"
          access   = "proxy"
          isDefault = true
        }]
      }
      prometheus = {
        enabled = true
        persistence = {
          enabled          = true
          storageClassName = "gp2"
          size             = "8Gi" 
        }
      }
      alertmanager = {
        enabled = true
        persistence = {
          enabled          = true
          storageClassName = "gp2"
          size             = "2Gi" 
        }
      }
      loki = {
        persistence = {
          enabled          = true
          storageClassName = "gp2"
          size             = var.loki_storage_size
        }
        limits_config = {
          retention_period = var.loki_log_retention
          compactor_retention_enabled = true
        }
        image = {
          registry   = "docker.io"
          repository = "grafana/loki"
          tag        = "2.9.3" # must be this version because the bundled one does not work (bugs)
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}




#########################################
### Deploy Promtail for log shipping
resource "helm_release" "promtail" {
  name       = "promtail"
  repository = "https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts"
  chart      = "promtail"
  namespace  = "infra"

  values = [
    jsonencode({
      config: {
        lokiAddress: "http://loki.infra:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
        filepath: "/var/log/containers/*.log"
      }
    })
  ]

  depends_on = [helm_release.loki]
}

but the problem is that the alertmanager and prometheus PVCs from the Terraform (UAT EKS) are not being bound for they are missing storage class definition :(
$ kubectl -n infra get pvc
NAME                          STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   VOLUMEATTRIBUTESCLASS   AGE
data-rabbit-rabbitmq-0        Bound     pvc-ffea3acd-fdd2-40dc-bef9-f5d45e9c3b26   8Gi        RWO            gp2            <unset>                 56m
data-rabbit-rabbitmq-1        Bound     pvc-8aac39e0-2859-4eeb-809f-b417f6bcedc5   8Gi        RWO            gp2            <unset>                 56m
data-rabbit-rabbitmq-2        Bound     pvc-5b5bce04-34f4-4948-9fc8-43a1ebb4e2c2   8Gi        RWO            gp2            <unset>                 56m
loki-prometheus-server        Pending                                                                                       <unset>                 4m10s
storage-loki-0                Bound     pvc-7bb1e4aa-1561-4a59-b4d7-30a3814f6d9b   10Gi       RWO            gp2            <unset>                 53m
storage-loki-alertmanager-0   Pending                                                                                       <unset>                 53m

loki-prometheus-server.yaml
$ kubectl get pvc loki-prometheus-server -n infra -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: infra
  creationTimestamp: "2024-12-20T08:55:09Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: prometheus-19.7.2
    component: server
    heritage: Helm
    release: loki
  name: loki-prometheus-server
  namespace: infra
  resourceVersion: "43914"
  uid: ***moderated***
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Pending

storage-loki-alertmanager.yaml
$ kubectl get pvc storage-loki-alertmanager-0 -n infra -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-12-20T08:48:44Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alertmanager
  name: storage-loki-alertmanager-0
  namespace: infra
  resourceVersion: "41942"
  uid: ***moderated***
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Pending

which is weird, for the manually deployed helms were deployed fine in the DEV EKS
$ kubectl get pvc loki-prometheus-server -n infra -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: infra
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
    volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: ***moderated***
    volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
  creationTimestamp: "2024-12-17T14:49:20Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: prometheus-19.7.2
    component: server
    heritage: Helm
    release: loki
  name: loki-prometheus-server
  namespace: infra
  resourceVersion: "110099267"
  uid: ***moderated***
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  storageClassName: gp2
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: ***moderated***
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  phase: Bound

$ kubectl get pvc storage-loki-alertmanager-0 -n infra -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
    volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: ***moderated***
    volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
  creationTimestamp: "2024-12-17T14:49:21Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alertmanager
  name: storage-loki-alertmanager-0
  namespace: infra
  resourceVersion: "110099264"
  uid: ***moderated***
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: gp2
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: ***moderated***
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  phase: Bound


It seems that you haven't set storage class in both UAT and DEV. And DEV cluster just happen to have default storage class. If you list sc on DEV it should look similar to following:
kubectl get sc
NAME
gp2 (default)

In order to set storage class on prometheus and alertmanager explicitly you would need to provide following:
--set prometheus.server.persistentVolume.storageClass=gp2 \
--set prometheus.alertmanager.persistence.storageClass=gp2

